# How do I solve this error: "Class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase could not be found"

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, phpunit, cruisecontrol, phpundercontrol

I am trying to run a SeleniumTestCase with phpunit but I cannot get it to run with the phpunit.bat script.

My goal is to use phpunit with Selenium RC in CruiseControl & phpUnderControl. This is what the test looks like:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertTitleEquals('Example Web Page');
    }
}
```

I also got PEAR in the include_path and PHPUnit installed with the Selenium extension. I installed these with the pear installer so I guess that's not the problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Remy

Comment: for what ever reason I can not find PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase in /PEAR/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php, isn't it supposed to be there?

Answer (score 16):

hopefully this is a more definitive answer then the ones given here (which did not solve me problem). If you are getting this error, check your PEAR folder and see if the "SeleniumTestCase.php" file is actually there:

```
/PEAR/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php
```

If it is NOT, the easiest thing to do is to uninstall and reinstall PHPUnit using PEAR ...

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit

pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium

pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

After doing the above and doing just the single install, PHPUnit_Selenium was also auto installed, I'm not sure if this is typical, so some might have to do...

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Also see http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/installation.html for PEAR channel info if needed...

Comment: This is what I needed to do in order to fix this, thanks farinspace.

Comment: well that uninstalled phpunit but now it says no releases available...great

Comment: using ```pear install phpunit/PHPUnit``` gave this error : ```invalid package name/package file ```phpunit/PHPUnit```

Comment: while I have not used phpunit in some time, i think the best way going forward would be to use the phar package, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

Answer (score 6):

Here is the deal:

If you have a "Class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase could not be found in (testcase file name)" problem, you have to do the following two things:

***1. Rename the file of test case to the name of the class it contains***
***2. You should launch phpunit from the folder with your tests.***

This should fix your problem.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at one of the comments in the require_once entry in the php manual..

http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php#62838

"require_once (and include_once for that matters) is slow

Furthermore, if you plan on using unit tests and mock objects (i.e. including mock classes before the real ones are included in the class you want to test), it will not work as require() loads a file and not a class."

Answer (score 1):

I just renamed the file my test was in to "WebTest.php" (the name of the class it contains) and the test runs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not presume that the pear install occurred without problems.

I had installed phpunit through pear but despite it saying the install went fine when I looked inside the folder, I had all these files starting with .tmp, eg PHPUnit/Util/.tmpErrorHandler.php so naturally when i ran a test for the 1st time it gave me the same error as above. After checking that indeed the file wasn't there I did a manual install of PHPUnit to the same folder as pear and alas, all was fine. I'm in Mac/leopard.

About Selenim RC don't forget to start it by running in terminal
java -jar /path/to/file/selenium-server.jar

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following sample from PHPUnit tutorial was working while the same error appeared in the test that I had written.
The solution was a surprise. Ensure that your class is inside a `<?php .. ?>` block and not a `<? .. ?>` block in the script.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Also, try the flag --syntax-check for PHPUnit on the command line.
Otherwise, PHPUnit may silently ignore the errors in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i solved this problem:

1. Make sure that curl extension for php is installed,
    e.g for ubuntu `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`
2. Enter `sudo  pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium`

After that you should have the missing file installed

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class WebTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
```

It can be namespace issue, as it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I use inline command : if lauching test from PhPunit dir i have the error while whent launching it from test dir I havne't the error ...

but I still haven't any acces to selenium server ... shall I have to launch it before or not.

If Yes it's strange that we havne't to specify any handle to PhPUnit ...

Answer (score 0):

When it fails it doesn't always print out the most verbose error messages.

Always remember to start Selenium too prior to running test.

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar

Here is an example of code that was working for myself. http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/p1.php?id=php002. Obviously there are a lot of different way to write the test suite, and launch the test case but I used the set_class_path to get rid of class issues at first.