# Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

I installed phpunit-selenium using composer according to here; https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html

The problem is that I only have selenium 2 for phpunit. PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase.php is there. But the file PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.php does not exist in the extension map where it supposed to be. So selenium 1 function can not be used.

How can I get selenium 1 for php unit using composer (on a windows machine)? 
I know there is an answer involving pear; [How do I solve this error: "Class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77835/how-do-i-solve-this-error-class-phpunit-extensions-seleniumtestcase-could-not)

But pear is not preferred because composer is shared with the team. It would save installing it.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I needed to move back a version in phpunit-selenium:

```
  "require-dev": {  
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "1.4.*"
}
```

instead of using the latest version which probably only works with selenium 2.

```
  "require-dev": {  
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
}
```